# Sequences and convergence with real numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

So this is the question that I have no idea how to start...

Let $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and $(b_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be sequences in $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose that $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $0$ and $(b_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is bounded.

Show that there exists $K$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $|a_nb_n|\le K|a_n|$.

Comment: This constant $K$ is simply the constant bounding $b_n$. Do you know the definition of bounded sequence? There exists a constant $K > 0$ such that... This is your constant.

Comment: Are you sure this is the question you intended?  The convergence of $\{a_n\}$ is not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

$\{ b_n \}$ is bounded, so exists $M$ such that $b_k < M$ for all $k$. Then

$$| a_n b_n | = |b_n||a_n| < M |a_n|$$

Comment: In other words M is K, as in the constant?

Comment: @user321600 There are a lot of constants for which that inequality holds true. But yes, you can take as $K$ the constant bounding the sequence $b_n$